# CloseDate Using Apex

Tags: apex, opportunity, date, closedate

How Do i need to Write APex Code for the CloseDate on Opportunity object?

```
 Opportunity Opp= new Opportunity();
    Opp.Name='Beginner';
    Opp.CloseDate= ?????;
    Opp.StageName='Proposal';
    insert Opp;
```

can someone help me out with this ?

Comment: did you check the documentation for date fields, what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
Opp.CloseDate= System.today();
```

or

```
Opp.CloseDate = Date.newInstance(2017, 12, 31);
```

If you have a string, then you should convert by either of the following ways:

```
Opp.CloseDate = Date.parse('10/14/2017');

Opp.CloseDate = Date.valueOf('2017-12-15');
```

For more information, refer [Date Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use TODAY() function as well.
for example,
opp.closeDate=TODAY()+1; will give you tomorrow's date
or ,opp.closeDate=TODAY() will give you today's date